# ASP.NET: Can I read the ViewState to restore a control in the client site?

Tags: asp.net

I am curious: is it possible to read the initial state of a DropDownList control using JavaScript?

Let’s say that when the page is loaded in the browser, the dropdown has ten options. Then, using JavaScript I remove all the options.

Can I read the ASP.NET ViewState to get the initial ten options and restore them?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes you can use JavaScript to read the viewstate values as they are stored in a field called `__viewstate`, which is rendered in the browser as an input field like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="..." />
```

The problem you will run into is the `__viewstate` value is encrypted.

My suggestion is to use a hidden field to store the values of the dropdown or whatever else you want to store and then access the value like this:

```
<input type="hidden"  id="hiddenField" runat="server" value="" />
```

Then in your code-behind, since the input has the `runat="server"` you can set the value to whatever you wish, like this:

```
hiddenField.Value= ViewState["dropdownvalues"].ToString();
```

Finally, you can use JavaScript to get the values from the hidden field, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
     function test() 
     {
         var name = document.getElementById('hiddenField').value;
         alert(name)
     }
</script>
```

Comment: I had to specify that, in my case, the ViewState is not encrypted. I was asking to read the ViewState because the code behind is kind of old and it already binds the data in the DropDownList. I'd like to add client-side code without modifying the server-side but I'm starting to think it is not a good idea and should refactor the server and client sides.